# Setting button associated with Enter key

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button

I have a form that has three panels with different buttons in each panel. Depending on some setup prior to showing the form, two of the three panels are hidden (width is set to 0). In that same setup code I also have been trying to adjust the button that is "clicked" when the user hits enter, so that it's one of the buttons in the panel that is not hidden, but it doesn't work. The same button is always used when I hit Enter while testing.

For point of reference, based on [Why is my basic default .acceptbutton is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470611/why-is-my-basic-default-acceptbutton-is-not-working), I have already had the code that hides the panels set Focus() and AcceptButton to the button I'm wanting to use, but never the less, when I hit Enter after the form shows the wrong button is used. For reference here is the setup code:

```
''' <summary>
''' Displays a custom error prompt with the indicated button(s) displayed, and returns
''' the user's response
''' </summary>
''' <param name="txt">The text to display in the prompt</param>
''' <param name="btns">The button(s) to use</param>
''' <param name="MWin">The MainWin instance holding the ErrWin instance that
'''' all this information impacts</param>
''' <returns>A Boolean on whether to continue the application or exit it </returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Function ErrBox(ByVal txt As String, ByVal btns As String, _
    ByVal MWin As MainWin) As Boolean
    '
    Dim ret As Boolean = True 'default to true as we continue the application in most 
        'cases
    Dim pt As New Point

    Try
        'Setup the error window
        MWin.EWin.FullLog.Add(Now() & " - " & txt) 'add to the full log for dump to 
            'admin notice email if needed
        MWin.EWin.Prompt.Text = txt
        Select LCase(btns)
            Case "yn"
                'Resize the yn panel correctly & adjust location
                pt.X = 195
                pt.Y = 415
                MWin.EWin.YNPanel.Location = pt
                MWin.EWin.YNPanel.Width = 191
                MWin.EWin.YNPanel.Height = 30

                'Make sure okpanel & exitpanel are hidden
                pt.X = 0
                pt.Y = 415
                MWin.EWin.OkPanel.Location = pt
                MWin.EWin.OkPanel.Width = 0
                pt.X = 0
                pt.Y = 385
                MWin.EWin.ExPanel.Location = pt
                MWin.EWin.ExPanel.Width = 0

                'Put focus on Yes
                MWin.EWin.YBtn.Focus()
                MWin.EWin.Abutton = MWin.EWin.YBtn
            Case "ok"
                'Resize the ok panel correctly & adjust location
                pt.X = 240
                pt.Y = 415
                MWin.EWin.OkPanel.Location = pt
                MWin.EWin.OkPanel.Width = 86
                MWin.EWin.OkPanel.Height = 30

                'Make sure ynpanel & exitpanel are hidden
                pt.X = 0
                pt.Y = 415
                MWin.EWin.YNPanel.Location = pt
                MWin.EWin.YNPanel.Width = 0
                pt.X = 0
                pt.Y = 385
                MWin.EWin.ExPanel.Location = pt
                MWin.EWin.ExPanel.Width = 0

                'Give focus to ok
                MWin.EWin.OkBtn.Focus()
                MWin.EWin.Abutton = MWin.EWin.OkBtn

            Case "exit"
                'Resize the exit panel correctly & adjust location
                pt.X = 240
                pt.Y = 415
                MWin.EWin.ExPanel.Location = pt
                MWin.EWin.ExPanel.Width = 191
                MWin.EWin.ExPanel.Height = 30

                'Make sure okpanel & exitpanel are hidden
                pt.X = 0
                pt.Y = 415
                MWin.EWin.OkPanel.Location = pt
                MWin.EWin.OkPanel.Width = 0
                pt.X = 0
                pt.Y = 385
                MWin.EWin.YNPanel.Location = pt
                MWin.EWin.YNPanel.Width = 0

                'Give focus to Exit
                MWin.EWin.Abutton = MWin.EWin.ExitBtn
                MWin.EWin.ExitBtn.Focus()

            Case Else
                'Bad value, log the issue and then notify the user
                MWin.EWin.FullLog.Add(Now() & " - Inproper value provided for btns." _
                    & " Limited to 'YN', 'Ok', or 'Exit'. " & btns & " was provided.")
                MsgBox("An error occured while attempting to report an error. The " _
                    & "application will attempt to continue to function, but the " & _
                    "action immediately prior" & _
                    " to this prompt appearing will not be able to successfully " & _
                    "complete.", vbOKOnly, "Error in Error Handling")
                'Set ret to True
                ret = True
                Return ret
                Exit Function
        End Select
    Catch ex As Exception
        MWin.EWin.FullLog.Add(Now() & " - Error while trying to setup the ErrWin." & _
            " Details: " & ex.Message)
        MsgBox("An error occured while attempting to report an error. The " & _
            "application will attempt to continue to function, but the action " & _
            "immediately prior" & _
            " to this prompt appearing will not be able to successfully complete.", _
            vbOKOnly, "Error in Error Handling")
        'Set ret to True
        ret = True
        Return ret
        Exit Function
    End Try

    Try
        MWin.EWin.Btns = btns
        'Show the error window
        MWin.EWin.ShowDialog()

        'Capture the return
        ret = MWin.EWin.Ret

        'Clear btns and ret on ewin
        MWin.EWin.Btns = ""
        MWin.EWin.Ret = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        MWin.EWin.FullLog.Add(Now() & " - Error while showing ErrWin, reading its " _
            & "response, or clearing its variables. Details: " & ex.Message)
        MsgBox("An error occured while attempting to report an error. The application" -
            & " will attempt to continue to function, but the action immediately " & _
            "prior" & _
            " to this prompt appearing will not be able to successfully complete.", _
            vbOKOnly, "Error in Error Handling")
        'Set ret to True
        ret = True
    End Try

    Return ret
End Function
```

Despite those explicit Focus and AcceptButton lines, the OkBtn always is what's "clicked" when Enter is hit. One last note, there is no code for the Load or Shown events for the form in question, so nothing there to contradict the above code. Any guidance on what I'm missing would be much appreciated

Comment: Disable the other buttons (IE: MWin.EWin.ExitBtn.Enabled = False/True and so on depending on the context)

Comment: That got it, thanks Steve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just disable the other buttons in such a way that also if they are hidden they cannot receive the Enter key

```
Select LCase(btns)
    Case "yn"
        .....
        MWin.EWin.ExitBtn.Enabled = False
        MWin.EWin.YBtn.Enabled = True
        MWin.EWin.OkBtn.Enabled = False

        'Put focus on Yes
        MWin.EWin.YBtn.Focus()
        MWin.EWin.Abutton = MWin.EWin.YBtn
    Case "ok"
        .....
        MWin.EWin.ExitBtn.Enabled = False
        MWin.EWin.YBtn.Enabled = False
        MWin.EWin.OkBtn.Enabled = True

        'Give focus to ok
        MWin.EWin.OkBtn.Focus()
        MWin.EWin.Abutton = MWin.EWin.OkBtn

    Case "exit"
        .......
        'Give focus to Exit
        MWin.EWin.ExitBtn.Enabled = True
        MWin.EWin.YBtn.Enabled = False
        MWin.EWin.OkBtn.Enabled = False

        MWin.EWin.Abutton = MWin.EWin.ExitBtn
        MWin.EWin.ExitBtn.Focus()

    Case Else
        ....
End Select
```

Probably it is preferable to enable/disable directly the containers of the  buttons  (IE the groupboxes) just to be sure that everything in the hidden containers doesn't interfere with your logic (for example the taborder followed when the user moves between controls using the TAB key)